# Sound not working Focal Fossa Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, kernel, 20.04, bluetooth, bug-reporting

I have been using ubuntu 20.04 recently and have a HP pavillion laptop with B&O speakers. However i am not able to hear any sound. though, Bluetooth is working fine.

I have tried many solutions such as :

*`sudo apt purge timidity-daemon`

*`sudo alsa force-reload`

*`sudo apt install pavucontrol` and running `pavucontrol`.

**None** of the solutions have worked for me yet.

EDIT:
Later I assumed it to be a kernel bug and say a solution using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kaihengfeng/fix-lp1869819
sudo apt-get update
```

after that i have tried reinstalling pulseaudio. And now bluetooth devices just after getting connected are automatically disconnected, do not play any sound either.

EDIT2: I would like to present the following outputs

1.1. cat /proc/asound/cards

```
 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xb4000000 irq 17
```

1.2. lsmod | grep snd

```
snd_soc_hdac_hdmi      36864  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   122880  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_soc_dmic           16384  0
snd_sof_pci            20480  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    69632  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_byt      20480  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof               106496  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_hda_ext_core       28672  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    32768  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_soc_acpi_intel_match
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof
snd_soc_core          245760  5 snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_dmic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         131072  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           90112  10 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    90112  19 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

1.3. lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel

```
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         131072  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           90112  10 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               106496  9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                    90112  19 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

1.4. inxi -SA (you may have to install inxi)

```
System:    Host: jarvis Kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.3 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS driver: sof-audio-pci 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP107GL High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-42-generic
```

1.5. lspci -nnk | grep -n -A 4 Audio

```
47:00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
48- Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [103c:8478]
49- Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
50- Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci
51-00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller [8086:a323] (rev 10)
--
62:01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fb9] (rev a1)
63: Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller [103c:8478]
64- Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
65- Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
66-02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Alcor Micro AU6625 PCI-E Flash card reader controller [1aea:6625]
67- Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company AU6625 PCI-E Flash card reader controller [103c:8478]
```

1.6. uname -a

```
Linux jarvis 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

1.7. aplay -l

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

1.8. sudo lshw -C multimedia (without sudo if you can't)

```
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: a1
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:b4000000-b4003fff
  *-usb:1
       description: Video
       product: HP Wide Vision HD Camera
       vendor: Chicony
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@1:5
       version: 32.48
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci latency=32
       resources: irq:16 memory:b451c000-b451ffff memory:b4100000-b41fffff
```

1.9. dpkg -l | grep alsa

```
ii  alsa-base                                     1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                  all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-topology-conf                            1.2.2-1                               all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                                 1.2.2-1ubuntu0.1                      all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                    1.2.2-1ubuntu1                        amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                       1.16.2-4                              amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
```

1.10. dpkg -l | grep linux- | grep $(uname -r)

```
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic                5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic                  5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic                5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic          5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-440-5.4.0-42-generic     5.4.0-42.46                           amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.4.0-42
```

1.11. modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel

```
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-hda-core.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-codec.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-dspcfg.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.4.0-42-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko
```

1.12. grep intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

```
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
```

Comment: I saw some fix related to kernel involving `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kaihengfeng/fix-lp1869819`. I have added the ppa I'm not quite sure does adding it and updating apt enough to make this patch working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after surfing a lot through the net and reading about options of alsa for NVIDIA aound controller I got the following solution

2 files are to be changed

1. `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and
2. `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

### Changes in File 1.

- open the file using root
- add the following to the bottom of the line `blacklist snd_soc_skl`
- save and exit the file.

### Changes in File 2.

- open the file using root
- add the following line to the bottom of the file `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0`
- save and exit the file

Reboot and Enjoy with the restored sound!

Comment: Files are inverted, changes for "File 2" should be applied to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and viceversa

Comment: @Vallo thanks I have corrected that part now

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:
[Avoid missing kernel linux-modules-extra-XX-generic when updating kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265137/avoid-missing-kernel-linux-modules-extra-xx-generic-when-updating-kernel)
may help avoiding the problem in the future, in some cases.

This answer is possibly more of a comment, but it would not fit as such.
So this is my five cents to try helping.

I have recently faced an issue with sound in 20.04, and it was painful to solve it.
[Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul)
At the bottom of the question I list just a few of the sources I read.

Based on that experience (see [my own answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259815/226614)), I suggest you add the following info:

1. Output of

   1.1.  `cat /proc/asound/cards`

   1.2. `lsmod | grep snd`

   1.3. `lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel`

   1.4. `inxi -SA` (you may have to install `inxi`)

   1.5. `lspci -nnk | grep -n -A 4 Audio`

   1.6. `uname -a`

   1.7. `aplay -l`

   1.8. `sudo lshw -C multimedia` (without `sudo` if you can't)

   1.9. `dpkg -l | grep alsa`

   1.10. `dpkg -l | grep linux- | grep $(uname -r)`

   1.11. `modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel`

   1.12. `grep intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
2. Detail on

   2.1. Was sound working at any time? It seems it was, but I am not certain.

   2.2. If you have a "similar" working system #2 available.

Point 2.2. was key for me.
If you have that option, I suggest you use it.

If not, you might consider installing another Ubuntu 20.04.
It took me (roughly) some 6 cumulative hours fixing the problem (perhaps more).
And it might have taken me possibly 6 more without my #2.
So installing another Ubuntu is a competitive attempt.

You can do that, for instance, by squeezing your current partitions and and adding another Ubuntu side-by-side.
You may possibly require not more than 30Gb. You may even use your old `/home` if it resides in its own partition (a recommended practice).

Note: I am not sure the fix you tried may have "tainted" your base system.

Comment: I have added all my required files.
Also my sound card was never working since I installed Ubuntu 20.04. However I also have Manjaro KDE 20 running with sound.